# nivida drivers install help

Tags: drivers

Hell i've been trying to install nivida drivers forever now and I keep running into this error.

```
    Setting up nvidia-prime (0.6.2) ...
nvidia-prime start/running, process 4736
Setting up screen-resolution-extra (0.17.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-settings (343.13-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.3) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-331
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I restart my display is messed up. My second monitor is blank and my main is running a very low resolution. In the display options it's only one monitor.

Comment: what commands did you use to try to install it?

Comment: If i'm not mistaking it was sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 I have tried a bunch after reinstalling ubuntu who knows how many times today.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in the terminal: Firstly remove this package if it is installed as it apparently causes Nvidia Settings to crash on start

```
sudo apt-get purge libvdpau-va-gl1
```

If you have Nouveau installed, remove that too as it is not compatible with the proprietary  product you are after instead for Nvidia. Next, install Nvidia prime, with the drivers you want

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319 nvidia-prime
```

Reboot.

Comment: System program problem detected
Do you want to report the problem now?

Terminal
"E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"